# HTML Video plays double when autoplay is enabled

Tags: html, wordpress, video

On my wordpress site, when adding a video via the standard HTML Video tag, and then adding autoplay to it - when i then reload the page it sure autoplays but after a few seconds another instance starts the audio and then the audios are overlapping each other. How can i prevent this? This is my simple code.

```
<video width="400" controls autoplay>
  <source src="/uploads/2018/04/ML_video-converted-with-Clipchamp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: the link is: blivleder.com

Comment: @ArtiSingh it should have been added above

Comment: @ArtiSingh I don't know if it was intentional, but you deleted your answer.

Comment: I believe the main issue here is visual composer adding so much code to the page that it causes the video itself to break and not work as intended. I cannot see why the audio is actually playing twice, I've debugged your site and the source is only loading once so it's peculiar why we are hearing it twice. Have you tried uploading the video to a different outlet, let's say YouTube or Vimeo, and then integrating it into Visual Composer that way? I'm willing to bet this will work rather than trying to use the native video block.